# How to display files from a directory on a datatable using primefaces and jsf?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am new to Primefaces and JSF. I need to create a screen that allows Operators to view all files in a certain directory for that days date. This will need to be displayed on the datatable. I am not sure how to do it. I am not using a database at all, only directories. Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: The PrimeFaces datatable does not have any knowledge of where the data in de model comes from, nor does the plain jsf `h:datatable`. Look in the PF showcase, no datatabase at all. It just uses a list or collection or array... So take a step back and see how you can add files from a directory to a list. Nothing JSF or PrimeFaces related in here...